# The reload hotkey cmd+r doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I have setup a react-native app and it can be launched by running the "react-native run-ios" from a terminal. I can see that there is another terminal popup to listening on 8081 port. However, when I press cmd+r on the simulator it doesn't do the refresh. I can see that the watchman is running. If there is an error on my javascript, I am able to refresh the simulator by clicking the Refresh button on the bottom of the screen. I don't understand why the hot-key doesn't work. Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: Sometimes you hit this because the project schema is "release" instead of "debug". Go to XCode > Product > Schema > Edit Schema to change it and try again.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably need to check that the simulator is connected to your hardware. To do this, go to Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard in your simulator menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who's tried this, it hasn't worked, and you're using Cocoapods:

1. In *[Xcode_project].xcworkspace*, click Pods on the left within the project directory view.
2. Click **Pods** under project
3. Under **Configurations** select **Use Debug for command-line builds**

Clean project; rebuild; run.

[image: Xcode screenshot]